# django get filename from uploaded file using formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to get the filename of an uploaded file, using formsets.

**views.py**

```
...
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        albumform = AlbumForm(request.POST)
        photoformset = PhotoFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if albumform.is_valid() and photoformset.is_valid():
            album = albumform.save(commit=False)
            album.user = request.user
            album.save()

            for photoform in photoformset:
                if photoform.is_valid() and photoform.has_changed():
                # here is where I'm lost
```

**forms.py**

```
...
class AlbumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('title', 'description')

PhotoFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    Photo,
    fields=('photo',),
    extra=4
)
```

`photoform['photo']` doesn't give me the filename directly, rather something like

`<input type="file" name="form-0-photo" accept="image/*" id="id_form-0-photo">`

which doesn't list `filename`

I've tried

```
photo = photoform.save(commit=False)
print(vars(photo))
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x000001F6326132E8>, 'id': None, 'album_id': 105, 'name': '', 'photo': <ImageFieldFile: phone.png>, 'photo_width': 600, 'photo_height': 416, 'thumbnail': '', 'status': '1'}
```

and I see the name there, but there's gotta be an easier way to get to it.

Comment: did you try `print(photoform.photo.name)`?

Comment: with `print(photoform.photo.name)` i get `AttributeError: 'PhotoForm' object has no attribute 'photo'`... with `print(photoform['photo'].name)` I get `photo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up working was
`print(photoform.cleaned_data.get('photo').name)`